# Hide Timeline using XML Code in share point Sandbox solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, sandbox-solution, task-list

How can I set **ShowTimelineIfAvailable** Property of Timeline in task list view using XML ?

I want to hide time line from the task list view. I've Sandbox Solution with page provisioning.

I'm creating web part using below code:

```
 <View
        List="Lists/Tasks"
        BaseViewID="5"
        WebPartZoneID="Header"
        WebPartOrder="1"
        ShowTimelineIfAvailable="False"> // It gives me Error. 
        <![CDATA[

          <webParts>
           <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
            <metaData>
             <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
             <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
            </metaData>
            <data>
             <properties>
              <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
              <property name="Title" type="string">My Task</property>
              <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
              <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">False</property>
              <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
             </properties>
            </data>
           </webPart>
          </webParts>
         ]]>
      </View>
```